# TabControl reordering ControlCollection when selecting a tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Alright, I have a weird one here again.

I have a running project where I'm building a tree of Controls/Components of a given form and use that to generate the shortest unique path to any one of them. Just as a context for the actual question.

Now I've had quite a bad time dealing with TabControl, which is finished quite badly on many levels, but most of it could be dealt with WinAPI calls. Fine. Now I have a problem which I can't figure out even when looking into the Microsoft reference codebase.

TabControl for some unknown reason reorders the ControlCollection based when a tab is selected. From a tiny test app, it seems far more random than I first anticipated. It's something that's unfortunately breaking my fallback method for dealing with unnamed Controls and the stable indexing is very important to me.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TabControlOrderTest
{
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TabControl tabControl1;
        private ListBox listBox1;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.tabControl1 = new TabControl();
            this.listBox1 = new ListBox();
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(566, 244);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(658, 34);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 251);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 2;

            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);

            this.ResumeLayout(false);


            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(
                    new TabPage($"tabPage{i}")
                    {
                        Name = $"tabPage{i}"
                    });
            }
        }

        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnShown(e);

            Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    for (var i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = i;
                    }
                });
        }

        private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pages = this.tabControl1.TabPages;
            var controls = this.tabControl1.Controls;
            this.Text = $"{pages.Count};{controls.Count}";
            this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0, count = this.tabControl1.TabCount; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(pages[i], controls[i]))
                {
                    continue;

                }

                this.listBox1.Items.Add($"{pages[i].Name} != {controls[i].Name}");
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Sometimes it's quite stable, sometimes it gets even more messy with every click. Could someone please give me a hint why is this happening? I would be so grateful for any clues.

EDIT: I'm asking about Controls property specifically because that's the universal place for Controls to store any underlying items. I could switch in my production code to TabPageCollection for TabControl specifically, but it could break more things than fix so that's why I'm trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: Why are you using `if (pages[i] == controls[i])`? It will never result in true because you are comparing a tabpage to a control !

Comment: The example just shows that at some point the ControlCollection gets reordered compared to the (stable?) TabPageCollection. Both hold TabPage instances, so you definitely can compared them.

Comment: No, we don't want "examples".  Post real code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @preciousbetine The Controls collection for a TabControl is the TabPages collection, more or less.

Comment: @LarsTech I can't, NDA. The example exactly shows my problem. I just need to know why the ControlsCollection gets reordered every time you select a tab because it screws up my indexing.

Comment: Then open a new project and throw some tabs on a TabControl.  Tabs don't reorder themselves unless you have code that reorders the tabs.  Your posted code doesn't do that for us.

Comment: I'm talking about Controls property that inherited from Control class. The tabs don't get reordered visually, but the ControlCollection does and that's THE PROBLEM.

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the problem.  Your code works perfectly fine on everything I've whipped up.

Comment: There is no guarantee that any `Controls` collection will present, each time, the same indexing. Since there are tons of ways to handle a specific indexing using classes (specialized class, `List<Control>` or `Dictionary <int, Control>` etc.), there's really no need to rely (for no good reason, IMO) on the behavior of something that never said it will behave like you want it to.

Comment: The TabControl is special, in that it won't actually create child controls until a Tab is selected.  My guess is, this feature might be doing something with the Controls  collection.  You could try peeking at the source code to see what it's doing under the hood when a tab is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've figured out the cause of this.

It's done by a Control.UpdateChildControlIndex(Control ctl) which gets called during handling WmWindowPosChanged

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/13dbf65f74593e7c.html

As it's obvious from the first lines, it can be optionally disabled.

It's kinda a pain before .NET 4.6 (as it requires the most ugly reflection code to do it).
From 4.6+, you just call

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Forms.AllowUpdateChildControlIndexForTabControls", false);
```

And profit. Hopefully.

In my case, I don't like the idea of switching some internal state of .NET FW for my Coded UI testing so I'll switch to different control collection for TabControl, as I've talk about in my question. But it's nice to know why before I do it.

Comment: FWIW the switch is deprecated in .NET Core 3.0
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/1139/commits/963e28f57e074af659d044f746e0ce4773ed5945